# Confusion regarding Munkres' lemma 13.3

Tags: general-topology

From Topology by James Munkres.

> Lemma 13.3. Let B and B' be bases for the topologies T and T'
>   , respectively, on
>   X. Then the following are equivalent:
>   (1) T' is finer than T .
>   (2) For each x ∈ X and each basis element B ∈ B containing x, there is a basis
>   element B' ∈ B' such that x ∈ B' ⊂ B.

My confusion began when considering the case when B' is smaller than B. For example, consider the set `X = {1,2,3}` and  `T= {{1,2,3}, {1,2} {1}}` and `T' = {T, {2,3}}` (that is, T' contains T and the set {2,3}). And let `B = T` and `B' = {1,2,3}`

Now considering `1 ∈ X` and basis element `{1,2}` which contains `1`, there should be a basis element in `B'` such that  `1 ∈ B' ⊂ B`, but the only basis element in `B'` is `{1,2,3}` which is not a subset of `{1,2}`

now according to figure 13.4 (added below) it should be the case that `B'` can be smaller than `B` but I can't see what I am missing.

Finally, I have been trying to draw insight from his proof. I think I have a flaw in my understanding of the topology being generated by the basis. Can we not just consider a single basis of a topology, like how I showed above?

> Blockquote
>   (1) ⇒ (2). We are given x ∈ X and B ∈ B, with x ∈ B. Now B belongs to T
>   by definition and T ⊂ T' by condition (1); therefore, B ∈ T'
>   . Since T' is generated
>   by B'
>   , there is an element B' ∈ B' such that x ∈ B' ⊂ B.

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand your definition of T’.  T’ cannot contain T.  It can only contain subsets of X. T is not a subset of X. It’s a set of subsets of X. If you mean that $T’=T \bigcup \{ \{1,2 \} \}$, then $T’=T$, since $\{1,2\} \in T$.

Comment: I also do not understand your definition of B’.  Do you mean $B’= \{ X \}$, which would be a basis for the trivial topology? Or do you mean $B’=\{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$, which would be a basis for the discrete topology?  Either way, it seems to me like you are defining $B’$ without showing that it is actually a basis for $T’$.

Comment: B' = {{1, 2, 3}} which is a basis for T'.

Comment: I see. I made a mistake let me edit T' to be T' = T or {{2,3}}. So T' = {{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1}, {2,3}} so now T is a subset of T' (T' is finer than T}

Comment: If B’ = {{1, 2, 3}} is a basis for T’, then every open set in T’ can be written as a union of elements of B’, meaning the only open sets are $X$ and the empty set.

Comment: it seems to me like you are not making sure that the B’ you define is actually a basis for T’. If you don’t ensure that B and B’ are actually bases for T and T’, then the hypotheses of the lemma aren’t satisfied.

Comment: Definition. If X is a set, a basis for a topology on X is a collection B of subsets of X
(called basis elements) such that
(1) For each x ∈ X, there is at least one basis element B containing x.
(2) If x belongs to the intersection of two basis elements B1 and B2, then there is a
basis element B3 containing x such that B3 ⊂ B1 ∩ B2.                                         Does not the basis element {{1,2,3}} contain every x in X?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98150/discussion-between-joe-and-bluesky11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal{T}=\{X,\{1,2\},\{1\},\emptyset\}$ is a topology (you forgot to mention the empty set), and $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{T}$ is trivially a base for it.

You then try to define a larger (finer) topology $\mathcal{T}'$ by setting $\mathcal{T}' = \{\mathcal{T}, \{2,3\}\}$ which is nonsense: this makes $\mathcal{T}$ an **element** of $\mathcal{T}'$ which is of the wrong type: elements of a topology on $X$ are subsets of $X$, so you should have written $$\mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T} \cup \{\{2,3\}\}$$

But this $\mathcal{T}'$ is not a topology, as $\{2,3\} \cap \{1,2\} = \{2\} \notin \mathcal{T}'$ so $\mathcal{T}'$ is not closed under finite intersections. And $\mathcal{B}' = \{1,2,3\}$ is a subset of $X$ not a subset (subfamily) of $\mathcal{T}'$ and even $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ (which is at least of the right type) is not a base for $\mathcal{T}'$. So the basic assumptions are wrong and the starting hypotheses are not satisfied.

A topology can have several different bases that generate it. This lemma can be used to recognise when two different bases on a set generate the same topology, e.g.